# How to enable container in bootstrap datepicker to append to a specific element?

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, jquery-ui, bootstrap-datepicker

How would you add specify the container option in bootstrap datepicker to enable the datepicker to append to a specific element?

I added the container option but its not working i.e. the datepicker is not opening when I add it. When I remove the container option, it defaults to body and the datepicker shows up fine.

I really want to enable the datepicker to append to only a specific element and stay fixed on scrolling but its not working at all i.e. the datepicker moves along with the scroll. Its really frustrating.

Here is the datepicker code,

```
$('#StartDate').bootstrapDP({ 
format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
startDate: defaultDate,
container: '#StartDate",
todayBtn: 'linked',
clearBtn: true,
beforeShowDay: function(Date){

    var curr_day = Date.getDate();
    var curr_month = Date.getMonth()+1;
    var curr_year = Date.getFullYear();        
    var curr_date=curr_month+','+curr_day+','+curr_year;    

    if(!(typeof nat_arr == "undefined")){

        if (nat_arr.indexOf(curr_date)>-1) return false;
    }

},
daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6],
todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate',dateChanged);
```

I tried all ends. I debugged the Jquery UI JS and found out that the issue has to do with something like display block not being appended when container added but i am not sure.

Please help me, it would be very kind!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple. All you had to do was add a div around the datepicker selector and give it an id. Thus, the following did the trick:

```
container: div#startDate,
```

This means that for a div around the datepicker selector text field with an id "startDate", append it to the element. Further, you may have to set the CSS property "overflow:visible" to the container element to allow the datepicker to be displayed by 'overflowing' the container.

Comment: `div#startDate` did not work for me, however i was able to use `$(".datepicker").parent()` to identify the nearest parent.

Comment: edit: `$(".datepicker:focus").parent()` OR `$(document.activeElement).parent()` are much better choices it seems.....